# Can we have more than 2 words in the name of a Parameter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a beginner at Swift.I would like to know if we can have more than 2 words in the name of a Parameter?

Also, are Parameter Name and Argument Label only used when there are 2 words in the name? What if there is only one word? Would we still call the parameter used inside the function as Parameter Name and the same one used outside as Argument Label or we would just call it a Parameter or we would call them both ?

Thankyou :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166 is pretty clear: Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter name. The argument label is used when calling the function; each argument is written in the function call with its argument label before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their argument label.

Answer (score 1):

Extend answer of Sweeper and Lumialxk

here **publicName** is the label of argument and **privateName** is the actual argument.

Label of argument defines related to the argument but when you wanted to use argument then you have to use actual argument

**Example: With label**

Below you can see **first** and **last** are the labels.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Example2: w/o label**

Below you can see not label for **first** but **last** is the label.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You can use `_` for the first argument only.

Hope above example clears you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not two words. The first one is public name, second private. You should use Camel-Case for more words.

```
func funcName(publicName privateName: Int) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages don't really have the concept of "words". Only "identifiers" and "tokens" exist.

To declare a parameter, you need three identifiers:

```
publicParameterName privateParameterName: Type
```

where `publicParameterName` can be `_`.

You can't use more than 2 identifiers in parameter names because that's how the language is designed. The compiler sees the first identifier and treats it as the public parameter name and it sees the second identifier and treats it as the private one. Then it sees a third identifier just before the `:`, What is it gonna treat it as? It does not know! That's why you get an error when you try to use three identifiers.

You can obviously use more than 2 "English words" in parameter names. Just make sure there are no spaces between those words, otherwise it will be treated as two identifiers This is an example:

```
func foo(aVeryLongParameterNameWithNineEnglishWords: Any)
```

As you can see, I used just one identifier for the parameter name in the above example. *You can do this*. If you only have one identifier, that will be treated as both the public and private parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 names corresponding to a parameter of the method in swift:

**1.** **External name** - name visible outside the method

**2.** **Internal name** - name visible inside the method

```
Example:

func funcName(externalName internalName: Int) 
{ 
     print("\(internalName)")
}

funcName(externalNamme: 3)
```

External name is `optional`, i.e. if you don't give any external name it will consider internal name as the external one.

```
Example:

func funcName(internalName: Int) 
{ 
     print("\(internalName)")
}

funcName(internalName: 3)
```

Also, if you don't want to give any name to the argument while calling, you can replace external name by an `underscore(_)`.

```
Example:

func funcName(_ internalName: Int) 
{ 
     print("\(internalName)")
}

funcName(3)
```